# memory in c programming

Tags: c, gstreamer

Hi i try to read a tkt input file to use it in my structure and it works fine but when i try to read the value image or adresse or nom it's empty 
someone have any idea?

this is the code :

```
int nombre_radio(char* fichier_radio)
{
   FILE* fichier = NULL;
   char buf[TAILLE_MAX_RADIO]="";
   int i;

   fichier = fopen(fichier_radio, "r");

   if (fichier != NULL)
   {
       i=0;
       while (fgets(buf, TAILLE_MAX_RADIO, fichier) != NULL)
       {
           i++;  
       }
   }

   fclose(fichier);
   return(i);
}
/* fonction pour récuperer l'image*/
void get_radio(int numero, char* fichier_radio, char* nom, char* adresse, char* image)
{
   FILE* fichier = NULL;
   char chaine[TAILLE_MAX_RADIO];
   int i;
   char im_temp[102400];

   fichier = fopen(fichier_radio, "r");

   if (fichier != NULL)
   {
       i=0;
       while (fgets(chaine, TAILLE_MAX_RADIO, fichier) != NULL && i<numero){i++;}

       strcpy(nom, strtok(chaine, "\t"));
       strcpy(adresse, strtok(NULL, "\t"));
       strcpy(im_temp, strtok(NULL, "\t"));
       if (strstr(im_temp, "\n") != NULL)
           strncpy(image, im_temp, strlen(im_temp)-1);
       else
           strncpy(image, im_temp, strlen(im_temp));
   }

   fclose(fichier);
   return;
}
```

this is the two function to read txt file and to use it to extract image adresse and nom
and i use the functions here:

```
int i;
char fichier_radio[1024];
strcpy(fichier_radio,"liste_radio.txt");
int nombre_Radio = nombre_radio(fichier_radio);

recording_asset *assets = malloc(sizeof(recording_asset) * 5000);

printf("nombre %d",nombre_Radio);
char *adresse = malloc (sizeof (*adresse) * 256);
char *nom = malloc (sizeof (*nom) * 256);
char *image = malloc (sizeof (*image) * 256);



    for(i=0; i<nombre_Radio; i++){      
        get_radio(i, fichier_radio, nom, adresse, image);
       printf("image : ",image[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Please tell us where it crashes and please format your code correctly.

Comment: Use a debugger to figure out exactly where the seg fault happens. Many of the functions you call (`malloc()`, `strtok()`) might fail and return `NULL`, but you never check for this.

Comment: Please indent the code properly.

Comment: unwind how can i check the function for that doesn't point to NULL?

Comment: I can think of worse ways to load a line-by-line series out of a file... No... I was wrong. I can't.

Answer (score 1):

1. Could you check `fclose(fichier);`: 

   If `fichier` is a `null` pointer, `fclose` should not be called. It results in a undefined behavior, hence might explain the crash you are observing.

   You should put `fclose(fichier);` inside your `if (fichier != NULL)` check condition.
2. In `nombre_radio`, please initialize `i` to a proper value, you will return garbage value if `fichier` is `NULL`.

Comment: The above answer was made for the initial question, which was about Segmentation Fault